# How can I find out if user has actually uploaded photo to instagram?

Tags: android, ios, instagram, instagram-api

My mobile app will post photos to instagram via the mobile sharing. I would like to know if the user actually uploaded the photo in the instagram app. And if he/she did - how can I get an id of an uploaded photo?

Answer (score 0):

Get that users recent photos using API and then compare the `created_time` of the most recent photo and then find a match for the image.

Comment: No, in this way I can't find out whether user has uploaded my photo because created_time doesn't correspond to the time when my app transferred its image to instagram app. created_time  is the time when image was uploaded to instagram server. So my app won't know if that was its image or some other image.

Comment: It turns out that the only way to identify my photo after it was uploaded to server is to check its gps attitude and langitude. But the problem is that Instagram only saves this information if user chose to set or create location for the photo and not otherwise.

Comment: u dont have to match exact created_time, just check if there is any photo posted after your share time first, then take those photos, and compare image matching, its complex, but will get u some results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Real Time Photo Updates](https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/) service. You can receive a notification to your backend when a new photo is uploaded.

Comment: How can my app know what photo was uploaded? The problem is that user can interrupt the process of uploading my app's photo by switching to some other photo and uploading it. And from my app's point of view - it's impossible to know which photo was eventually uploaded from instagram app.