# How to check if photo was shared on instagram?

Tags: ios, instagram, instagram-api

My app is sharing photos on instagram. Sharing is possible only via [Document Interaction](https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/). There's no callback AFAIK.
I'd like to check if the user has really shared the photo to reward him/her for doing it in the app. How to do that?

What I've tried and ISN'T a 100% guarantee solution:

1. combination of TAG and USER identification
2. image metadata
3. let the user afterwards identify the photo (bothering the user)

Comment: Wow, you repeated my yesterday's question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132193/how-can-i-find-out-if-user-has-actually-uploaded-photo-to-instagram